# Which is preferred practice for method parameters?

Tags: php, function, methods

I have dilemma on the format of method parameters for a function in PHP (could be any language). The following are the two candidates
**Candidate 1:**

```
function foo($param1,$param2,$param3,....$paramN)
```

and 
**Candidate 2:**

```
function foo ($arr) {
   $param1 = $arr['param1'];
   $param2 = $arr['param2'];
   $param3 = $arr['param1'];
   ...
   ...
   ...
   $paramN = $arr['paramN'];
}
```

I am leaning towards candidate 2 at the moment because I have couple of methods which have many parameters. But, I am also concerned that if I go on the path of Candidate 2, then my code has the risk to become unreadable and not easily maintainable. While Candidate 2 is also very enticing because now the order of the params becomes irrelevant (hence the method signature) but I am afraid debugging would become a pain in the butt.

So which is the recommended way? Which candidate to choose and why?

Comment: `$obj['param']` will throw an error. I think you mean `$obj->param`

Comment: If I pass that as an array then that would work.

Comment: Of course, but that isn't what you had in your code sample. :) Just wanted to give you a heads up in case you were mistaken.

Comment: Ah yes. Sorry @MatthewBlancarte for the confusion. Edited the question.

Comment: I would also like to point out that if your method needs many parameters, there is a chance your method is doing too much, and should be broken up into more than one method.

Comment: @xbonez. Yes that's a good point. The use case behind this question is that I have to insert a user's street address into the database and street address obviously has many parameters. I am not sure how to split that up.

Comment: @KaranAshar: Gotcha. Street address is a great case where you should use a class which has properties for all the address fields, and perhaps, you can add methods such as `validate()` too. Further, if needed, you can even override `__toString()` to display the street address easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of parameters are never nice to handle, I would personally opt for candidate 2 because it is more extensible. You can compensate for the "mess" with a validation logic that ensures, that all required parameters are set correctly.

The - in my opinion - best way is to refactor your code and split the method in several, maybe chainable parts so the complexity is reduced.

What might also be a nice option is to use [Value Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object) (or sometimes also Data Transfer Objects), to pass all the parameters in a sort of "container". In this way, it's ensured that only valid data can be passed, because the Value Object iself cares for its contents.

Comment: +1 and accepted because of Value Objects suggestion and splitting the method suggestion.